# JS console.log a 2d matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, console.log

I have a 2d matrix of arrays:

```
let matrix = 
[
[a, b, c], 
[d, e, f],
[g, h, i]
].
```

How can i print on the console any array on new line and without commas between elements?
Like this:

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

console.log(matrix.join('\n'))
prints any array on new line:

```
a, b, c
d, e, f
g, h, i
```

OK, but i don't want commas...

Comment: what about `matrix.forEach(item => console.log(item.join(' ')))`?

Comment: ... or, if you want to be unnecessarily "funky" ( :P ), you could do `console.log(matrix.reduce((str, item) => str += item.join(' ') + '\n', ''));`

Comment: Sulla prima proposta... Si anche io avevo fatto
    for( let row of matrix){console.log(row.join(' 
')) }. Ma non volevo usare un ciclo. La seconda invece e fighissima...wow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By improving your code, maybe you could modify it like this

```
const printMatrix = matrix.map((d) => d.join(" ")).join("\n")
console.log(printMatrix);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Javascript's [console.table()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table) instead of console.log()

This will display your array in table form, making it much more readable and easy to analyse
It is a little known feature, however useful when you have a dimensional array.

```
Matrix A: 
┌─────────┬───┬───┬───┐
│ (index) │ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │
├─────────┼───┼───┼───┤
│    0    │ 1 │ 2 │ 5 │
│    1    │ 3 │ 4 │ 6 │
└─────────┴───┴───┴───┘

Matrix A Transpose: 
┌─────────┬───┬───┐
│ (index) │ 0 │ 1 │
├─────────┼───┼───┤
│    0    │ 1 │ 3 │
│    1    │ 2 │ 4 │
│    2    │ 5 │ 6 │
└─────────┴───┴───┘
```